# Check for string in dataframe containing list of strings

Tags: r

I'm trying to find a way to lookup multiple values in a dataframe and return a value.  Simplified example:

```
df1 <- read.table(text="chk1    chk2    chk3    value
xx  aa;bb;cc    jj  1
xx;yy   dd;ee;ff    kk  2
zz  gg;hh;ii    ll;nn   3", header=T)

df2 <- read.table(text="val1    val2    val3
xx  bb  jj
xx  dd  kk
yy  ee  kk
zz  hh  jj
", header=T)
```

Lookup values `val1`, `val2`, and `val3` from `df2` in `df1`, return value from `df1`.

Desired results:

```
df2 <- read.table(text="
                  val1  val2    val3    value
xx  bb  jj  1
xx  dd  kk  2
yy  ee  kk  2
zz  hh  jj  NA
")
```

Tried `match x %in% y` and looping over the rows, can't get it to work.

Comment: Hi, please [**format your code**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/371738), this time I've helped you. Cheers.

Comment: I don't fully understand what the value is. For example, `xx` in rows 1 and 2 of `df2` matches both rows 1 and 2 in `df1`, why do the values in your desired output are 1 for the first line and 2 for the second? Do you mean to say that `val1` must match `chk1`, `val2` match `chk2` and `val3` match `chk3` at the same time?

Comment: @January I think that's the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possibility:

```
library(tidyverse)
df3 <- df2 %>% rowwise %>% 
       mutate(rowmatch=which(grepl(val1, df1$chk1) & 
                             grepl(val2, df1$chk2) & 
                             grepl(val3, df1$chk3))[1], 
              value=df1$value[rowmatch])
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  val1  val2  val3  rowmatch value
  <chr> <chr> <chr>    <int> <int>
1 xx    bb    jj           1     1
2 xx    dd    kk           2     2
3 yy    ee    kk           2     2
4 zz    hh    jj          NA    NA
```

Notes:

- the `[1]` is to ensure that only first of the matching rows is used.
- note that although `rowmatch` and `value` are identical in this example this is only because `df1$value` is equal to the row number.
- `tibble` behaves like a data.frame, but if you really prefer a data frame, add `%>% as.data.frame`

The same can be done with base R and apply:

```
df2$rowmatch <- with(df1, apply(df2, 1, function(x) 
    which(grepl(x["val1"], chk1) & 
          grepl(x["val2"], chk2) & 
          grepl(x["val3"], chk3))[1]))

df2$value <- df1$value[df2$rowmatch]
```

Comment: Thanks!   These are all great.

Answer (score 0):

another option would be splitting the values first:

```
df1 <- df1 %>% 
    splitstackshape::cSplit("chk1", ";", fixed = TRUE, direction = "long", drop = FALSE, type.convert = FALSE) %>% 
    splitstackshape::cSplit("chk2", ";", fixed = TRUE, direction = "long", drop = FALSE, type.convert = FALSE) %>% 
    splitstackshape::cSplit("chk3", ";", fixed = TRUE, direction = "long", drop = FALSE, type.convert = FALSE)
```

and then using join

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using two nested for loops. The logic is to take first row of `df2` and then start going through rows of `df1` to see if `df2$val1` matches `df1$chk`, `df2$val2` matches `df1$chk2` and `df2$val3` matches `df1$chk3`. I consider all values a match if there is at least one match per column. The caverat here is that if `df2` does not have unique rows, the last matching row from `df1` will be written to `df2`. But this can be changed by breaking out of the loop as soon as the match is found.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df2)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(df1)) {
    # Take i-th row and split by ;. Result is a vector of strings against
    # which we'll use match.
    i.split <- strsplit(as.character(unlist(df1[j, , drop = TRUE][-4])), ";")
    # Pairwise check columns from df1 and df2.
    all.ok <- all(mapply(FUN = function(x, y) {
      any(x %in% y)
    }, x = i.split, y = as.list(df2[i, 1:3])
    ))

    if (all.ok) {
      # If a match is found, write the value to df2.
      df2[i, "value"] <- df1[j, "value"]
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
  val1 val2 val3 value
1   xx   bb   jj     1
2   xx   dd   kk     2
3   yy   ee   kk     2
4   zz   hh   jj    NA
```